# Fetch data from XML file located in sdcard (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse

This is my first post here :-). I am developing an application for android in eclipse.

My question is I have put an XML file in sdcard with some elements like id,First name and lastname.

Form my UI i have one textbox and button. User will enter ID in the textbox and on click event of button I should fetch the data based on that ID. and display in TextView.

Any help please??

Thanks in advance. :-)

Here is a sample of XML file which is given to me,

```
<tblInsurees xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1">
  <ID>1</ID>
  <LastName>Family 1 (1-42-167)</LastName> 
  <OtherNames>FamMem1</OtherNames> 
  <DOB>01-01-85</DOB> 
  <PhotoFileName xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </tblInsurees>
- <tblInsurees xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1">
  <ID>2</ID>
  <LastName>Family 2 (1-4-16)</LastName> 
  <OtherNames>FamMem1</OtherNames> 
  <DOB>01-01-85</DOB> 
  <PhotoFileName xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </tblInsurees>
- <tblInsurees xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet1">
  <ID>3</ID>
  <LastName>Family 3 (1-4-16)</LastName> 
  <OtherNames>FamMem3</OtherNames> 
  <DOB>01-01-98</DOB> 
  <PhotoFileName xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </tblInsurees>
```

SO is it possible that somehow I can pass an ID as a parameter and I can just display the rest of the information like name and dob etc on my screen?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors do you get? I don't think anybody wants to do your work for you so you should show some form of troubleshooting and attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking.

Comment: What's the problem? Do you want to know method of doing this?

Comment: Thanks Emil and Shrikant, I have got many tutorial for reading XML but my only problem is how can I pass where criteria like we pass in SQL for example.

Comment: Check this 2 min tutorial: http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/parsing-xml-from-the-sdcard-using-xmlpullparser/) is a complete example with source. You just to get the File using

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "your_path/your_xml.xml");
```

Then do the further processing.

If you need example for different types of XML Parsers you can download complete example from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/).

Comment: HI Anas, is it possible for you to gimmi your email id please? I really need your help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...actually i went there and didnt find your email so I asked here.

Comment: HI Anas, I just sent you an email 10 mins ago.